# R dataframe Removing duplicates / choosing which duplicate to remove

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe that has duplicates based on their identifying ID, but some of the columns are different. I'd like to keep the rows (or the duplicates) that have the extra bit of info. The structure of the df is as such.

```
id <- c("3235453", "3235453", "21354315", "21354315", "2121421")
Plan_name<- c("angers", "strasbourg",  "Benzema", "angers", "montpellier")
service_line<- c("", "AMRS", "", "Therapy", "")
treatment<-c("", "MH", "", "MH", "")
df <- data.frame (id, Plan_name, treatment, service_line)
```

As you can see, the ID row has duplicates, but I'd like to keep the second duplicate where there is more info in `treatment` and `service_line`.

I have tried using

```
df[duplicated(df[,c(1,3)]),]
```

but it doesn't work as an empty df is returned. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:
First we replace all blank with NA, then we arrange be `Section.B` and finally `slice()` first row from group:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(-c(id, Plan_name),~ifelse(.=="", NA, .))) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(Section.B, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

```
 id       Plan_name   Section.B Section.C
  <chr>    <chr>       <chr>     <chr>    
1 2121421  montpellier NA        NA       
2 21354315 angers      MH        Therapy  
3 3235453  strasbourg  MH        AMRS
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter(if_all(treatment:service_line, ~ .x != ""))
```

-output

```
        id  Plan_name Section.B Section.C
1  3235453 strasbourg        MH      AMRS
2 21354315     angers        MH   Therapy
```

---

If we need ids with blanks and not duplicated as well

```
df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
    filter(n() == 1|if_all(treatment:service_line, ~ .x != "")) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  id       Plan_name   treatment service_line
  <chr>    <chr>       <chr>     <chr>       
1 3235453  strasbourg  "MH"      "AMRS"      
2 21354315 angers      "MH"      "Therapy"   
3 2121421  montpellier ""        ""
```

Comment: I made some edits to my post. Would you mind adjusting the script? I was a bit confused about the `starts_with` because the names that I had used were arbitrary. Sorry and thank you.